# Sencha Extjs 6 How to disable decimal input in numberfield

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I need to use numberfield in sencha extjs 6 but by default numberfield allow decimal input. My application is not required decimal input I tried `allowDecimals: false,` It may work on textfield. Is there any configs or ways to disable input?
Note: In PC I can write method to prevent it, but my app is running on ***mobile device*** therefore, I have no idea with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend you to use numberfield for this case. Of course this will accept all characters in desktop browsers. But you'll see this only accepts numbers in mobile by showing numeric keyboard.

Modern versions of Sencha Touch framework doesn't provide decimal precision params... but there's a way to overcome this issue. Just place these lines before you set values of your numberfield.

```
Ext.form.Number.override ({

    applyValue : function(value){
        var minValue = this.getMinValue(),
            maxValue = this.getMaxValue();

        if (Ext.isNumber(minValue) && Ext.isNumber(value)) {
            value = Math.max(value, minValue);
        }

        if (Ext.isNumber(maxValue) && Ext.isNumber(value)) {
            value = Math.min(value, maxValue);
        }

        value = parseFloat(value).toFixed(0); // where 0 is your decimal precision value
        return (isNaN(value)) ? '' : value;
    }
});
```

In this example you can see the implementation:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.form.Number.override({

            applyValue: function (value) {
                var minValue = this.getMinValue(),
                    maxValue = this.getMaxValue();

                if (Ext.isNumber(minValue) && Ext.isNumber(value)) {
                    value = Math.max(value, minValue);
                }

                if (Ext.isNumber(maxValue) && Ext.isNumber(value)) {
                    value = Math.min(value, maxValue);
                }

                value = parseFloat(value).toFixed(0); // where 0 is your decimal precision value
                return (isNaN(value)) ? '' : value;
            }
        });
        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'window',
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'numberfield'
            }]
        }).show();
    }
});
```

[Here is a working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1n9o)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but since I am new to sencha can you show me how to implement it?

Comment: @PhonSoyang please mark answer as correct if it works, i added a sencha fiddle to show you how it works

Comment: Actually, I don't want decimal input in numberfield but yours validate on decimal.